# Is it possible to have the users config files on special partition (on SSD) and symlinks in home folder (on HDD)?

Tags: ssd, configuration, symbolic-link

my system is installed on SSD and my home is on the HDD.

Is it possible (and useful) to make an extra partition (lets name it "config") on the SSD, move all my users config files to that partition and make symlinks to the config folders on the SSD in my home folder?

Comment: Possible, yes. Useful? Well, that really really depends on what your goal is. You can definitely have the `~/.config` , `~/.local` , or `~/.cache` folders from your `/home` partition stored and linked to another partition. I had to do a few times in a crunch that due to space limitations caused by multiple browser profiles taking up too much space in  `~/.cache`  or maven dependencies getting out of control size wise.  If your goal is related to `.conf` files then I doubt the boost you get is worth overcomplicating the disk tree, or risking of user profile loss if the partition gets corrupted.

Comment: My goal is to speed up the loading time of some programs (like Firefox and Thunderbird) by putting the configs and mailboxes on the SSD.

I have done that just hours ago and for me it seems that FF starts much faster and even TB starts quicker.
Maybe it's just a subjective impression ;-)